# MATLAB - Navigation in a struct

Tags: matlab, struct

I am working with a m script on a struct which has for example the following form `struct.substruct.subsubstruct.dataIwant`

Because the name of subsubstruct will change very often, but I want always execute my script on this struct my question is: Is there a way that matlab takes automatically the path.

Some information on the struct
`struct.substruct` contains only one element for example `subsubstruct`

I am looking for a way that matlab fills the name for `subsubstruct` in the statement `struct.substruct.subsubstruct.dataIwant` automatically.

Comment: See: [dynamic field referencing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/)

Comment: Dynamic field names and `fieldnames` is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: I don't get the idea of dynamic field reference. Could you please explain this with my example above.

Comment: @d4rty the linked blog post is quite clear. What do you not understand?

Comment: How I can use the `.()` notation to navigate in the desired way

Comment: using `fieldnames(struct.substruct)` gives me an array (with one element). How can i now paste it into the expression  `struct.substruct.???.dataIwant`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed above, one method is to utilize [dynamic field referencing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/).

An example, working from your comments, the assumption that `struct.substruct` contains only one element, and the [documentation for `fieldnames`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html):

```
mystruct.substruct.boogers.data = 12;

myfield = fieldnames(mystruct.substruct); % Returns 1x1 cell
mydata = mystruct.substruct.(myfield{1}).data;
```

Which returns:

```
mydata =

    12
```